# cut append variable bash

Tags: bash, append, cut

How can I append a string variable which I got through `cut` with next variable? In the file application.properties, I have value: myValue=/tmp/user/
I tried:

```
file=myfile.properties
path=$(cat application.properties | grep myValue=)
path2=$(echo $path | cut -d'=' -f 2- )
pathToFile=$path2$file
```

But output is only: `myfile.properties`. I need /tmp/user/myfile.properties

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Seems your path2 variable's value may be empty(just test it by assigning a test value and pathToFile=$path2$file should work), so better if you could let us know sample Input_file and expected output too.

Comment: *nod*. Running `bash -x yourscript` would be helpful for detecting where things are first behaving in an unexpected manner.

Comment: Path2 always contains value. it was tested, Input file (application.properties) have format:
**variable=value** ( For example: myValue=/tmp/user/)
next input is file ( these value is obtained from folder) For example: myfile.properies
**Output: tmp/user/myfile.properies**
I running bash yourscrip.sh

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `cut` for this at all: The shell's built-in string manipulation can do this trimming for you. (And don't use `cat`: It's more efficient to have `grep` read straight from the file than to have it reading from a separate process that then writes to a FIFO).

```
file=myfile.properies
path=$(grep myValue= <application.properties)
pathToFile=${path#*=}${file}
```